# How to reset Bitbucket password in GitHub Desktop on Mac?

Tags: macos, github, bitbucket

I'm using a Bitbucket repo in GitHub Desktop for Mac.

Since Atlassian changed my password, GitHub Desktop can't log in anymore and doesn't give me opportunity to provide new password. It says "Check preferences to make sure you're still logged in", but preferences only talks about GitHub account.

I'm able to push using command-line git.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Where can I submit issues for GitHub Desktop?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just found a solution. Open **Keychain Access** app, search for **bitbucket** and delete the records where it matches `bitbucket.org/mac`.

Then try to sync in Github Desktop again, it should ask you the new password.

[image: How to reset bitbucket password in github desktop mac]

Comment: not getting this info in keychain. any idea @SimonDepelchin

Comment: changing the permissions worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Recently I have faced a problem. My password wasn't save in keychain. My solution is described below...

1. Got to the folder ~/Library/Application Support/SourceTree
2. Delete the file {Username}@STAuth-bitbucket.org
3. Restart Sourcetree
4. Try to fetch, password filed appear, give your new password
5. Also can run "git fetch" command in terminal and need to type password
6. Done